# Returning top x most frequtenty based on quantity and number of occurencies

Tags: mysql, sql, database, grouping

I was really trying to solve this myself but I'm completely stuck.

I need to return the top 5 most frequently ordered items and their total price:

```
+-----+---+-----+
|name |qty|price|
+-----+---+-----+
|item1|1  |£5   |
+-----+---+-----+
|item2|4  |£1   |
+-----+---+-----+
|item1|1  |£5   |
+-----+---+-----+
|item2|5  |£1   |
+-----+---+-----+
|item1|1  |£5   |
+-----+---+-----+
|item1|1  |£5   |
+-----+---+-----+
```

The logic is obviously to group the items based on the frequency of `name`
And then to multiply the sum of `qty` with `price`

The resulting table should look something like this:

```
+-----+---+-----+-----+
|name |qty|price|total|
+-----+---+-----+-----+
|item1|4  |£5   |£20  |
+-----+---+-----+-----+
|item2|9  |£1   |£9   |
+-----+---+-----+-----+
```

As far as I've got is  `SELECT name, qty, price, (SUM(qty) * price) AS "total" ORDER BY qty DESC LIMIT 5`

But I know that's wrong. Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close.  You do need a `group by`, though, and to put the product *inside* the `sum()`:

```
SELECT name, count(*) as NumOrders,
       SUM(qty) as qty,
       SUM(qty * price) / SUM(qty) as average_price,
       SUM(qty* price) AS "total"
FROM t
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY sum(qty) DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

EDIT:

If you know the price is the same on all the rows, you could simplify this to:

```
SELECT name, count(*) as NumOrders,
       SUM(qty) as qty,
       price as average_price,
       SUM(qty) * price AS "total"
FROM t
GROUP BY name, price
ORDER BY sum(qty) DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed, however there was one bit of the question I forgot to add!

Comment: Ah, Literally just changed my question to ask that. That's spot on cheers buddy!